# Copying ScriptableObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way of mimicking MonoBehaviour copy semantics in ScriptableObjects?

Say I have a MonoBehaviour like so:

```
public class DummyClassBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public DummyClass           DummyClassTest;     //ScriptableObject
    public DummyClassBehaviour  DummyBehaviourTest; //Another DummyClassBehaviour
}
```

And a ScriptableObject:

```
public class DummyClass : ScriptableObject {
    public string Text = "";
}
```

When I duplicate(CTRL+D) a GameObject w/ DummyClassBehaviour attached, 'DummyBehaviourTest' copies as you would expect:  If it references a MonoBehaviour in the GameObject I'm copying, the copy mechanism updates the reference to the same MonoBehaviour type in the new GameObject.  If it references a MonoBehaviour in another GameObject, that reference remains unchanged.

The ScriptableObject, on the other hand, always references the original.  So I end up with *N* GameObject's all sharing the same ScriptableObject (DummyClass) from the original GameObject.  I'm using ScriptableObjects to allow serialization of non-Monobehaviour data classes.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to ScriptableObject :) What about prefabs? Maybe they perfrom as you want it

Comment: @Kay Hmm, that's a thought.  Can you dynamically modify prefabs in Editor mode?  My issue is that my actual "DummyBehaviour" has a List of "DummyClasses", some of which reference other "DummyClasses."  If I don't subclass ScriptableObject, Unity's serializer does a deep copy of my DummyClass and I end up with broken references.  One other thought I'd had was to assign a unique id to each class.

Comment: [EditorUtility.SetDirty](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) should make the changes persistent, but I have not yet used it. There are rare cases when another approach might help: A code generator. I have used this once in Unity for tweaking the ragdoll wizard, as a change in the Blender model was not reflected correctly in all cases. I wrote an article about it [C# Code Generator...](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-news/scio-development-blog-en/entry/open-source-c-code-generator-for-unity3d-ragdoll-wizard). But in most cases I would refrain from it

Comment: @Kay Prefabs seem to share the same serialization "problems".  if I use a ScriptableObject, all instances of that prefab share the same referenced classes after it's added to the scene.  :(  Code generation is an idea but a little unwieldy for my application.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, and please someone correct me if I'm wrong, you cannot modify the serialization behavior of a ScriptableObject to match that of a MonoBehaviour.  Namely that it should update references if a duplicate is made.

Instead I opted for a less than optimal solution, but it works.  My class is assigned a unique identifier that gets serialized like everything else.  I use this ID in DummyBehaviour.Awake() to create a lookup table that I can then use to reassign my DummyClass.

I'm not going to accept my own answer because I don't feel it answers my original question fully, but it's related:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DummyClass {
// Unique id is assigned by DummyBehaviour and is unique to the game object
    // that DummyBehaviour is attached to.
public int UniqueID = -1;
public string Text = "";

// Override GetHashCode so Dictionary lookups 
public override int GetHashCode(){
    int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + UniqueID;
    return hash;
}

    // override equality function, allows dictionary to do comparisons.
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))return false;

    DummyClass item = obj as DummyClass;
    return item.UniqueID == this.UniqueID;
}

    // Allow checks of the form 'if(dummyClass)'
public static implicit operator bool(DummyClass a) 
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null)) return false;
    return (a.UniqueID==-1)?false:true;
}


public static bool operator ==(DummyClass a, DummyClass b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
    {
         return object.ReferenceEquals(b, null);
    }

    return a.Equals(b);
}
public static bool operator !=(DummyClass a, DummyClass b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
    {
         return object.ReferenceEquals(b, null);
    }
    return !a.Equals(b);
}
}
```

And my MonoBehaviour:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DummyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<DummyClass> DummyClasses = new List<DummyClass>();

    // reassign references based on uniqueid.
    void Awake(){   
        Dictionary<DummyClass,DummyClass> dmap = new Dictionary<DummyClass,DummyClass>();
        // iterate over all dummyclasses, reassign references.
        for(int i = 0; i < DummyClasses.Count; i++){
            DummyClass2 d = DummyClasses[i];
            if(dmap.ContainsKey(d)){
                DummyClasses[i] = dmap[d];
            } else {
                dmap[d] = d;
            }
        }
        DummyClasses[0].Text = "All items same";
    }

    // helper function, for inspector contextmenu, to add more classes from Editor
    [ContextMenu ("AddDummy")]
    void AddDummy(){
        if(DummyClasses.Count==0)DummyClasses.Add(new DummyClass{UniqueID = 1});
        else {
            // Every item after 0 points to zero, serialization will remove refs during deep copy.
            DummyClasses.Add(DummyClasses[0]);
        }
        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: it can be done even simpler: serialize a global list (unique objects by id) then the list of references have NonSerializable attribute on the references, but you serialize their ID reference. In awake just match the references to the global list. Do not let unity serialize deep copies all over the place, and then assign correct references and enable garbage collector, to reduce overhead :) I know it's 2 years too late but.. only now I've encountered the same problems